# the usage of < /dev/null & in the command line

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, io-redirection, tcsh

I tried to run an example java program using the following command line. However, I do not know what is the trailing part `< /dev/null &` used for?

```
java   -cp  /home/weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 –t train_file  >& log < /dev/null &
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`< /dev/null` is used to instantly send EOF to the program, so that it doesn't wait for input (`/dev/null`, the null device, is a special file that discards all data written to it, but reports that the write operation succeeded, and provides no data to any process that reads from it, yielding EOF immediately). `&` is a special type of command separator used to background the preceding process.

Without knowing the program being called, I do not directly know why it is required to run it in this way.

Answer (score 10):

`</dev/null` disconnects the program's input from the terminal. Some programs react differently depending on what their standard input is connected to. With the redirection `</dev/null`, the program can tell that its input is not coming from a terminal, and will receive an end-of-file indication immediately if it tries to read from its standard input.

The lone `&` at the end causes the program to be executed in the background. This means that you get a shell prompt back immediately. Without the `&`, you would get a shell prompt back only when the program finishes executing.

Note that the standalone `&` is unrelated to `>&`. `>&` is a redirection operator (in tcsh, bash and zsh) which redirects both the program's standard output and the program's standard error to the file name specified after the operator (here `log`).

In other words, what the shell does when it sees this command line is:

- Start a process in the background. In the background process:

  - Connect standard input to `/dev/null` (the [null device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null)).
  - Connect both standard output and standard error to the file called `log` (creating the file if it doesn't exist yet, and truncating it if it exists).
  - Look for an executable file called `java` in the `$PATH`.
  - Execute that file with the 5 arguments: `-cp`, `/home/weka.jar`, `weka.classifiers.trees.J48`, `–t`, and `train_file`.